# Centered String Using tasm/tlink/dosbox in notepad++

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

How can I use the code in the picture to center my string?

I'am using notepad++ then tasm name.asm / tlink name / name. to execute the program. it just example of string that i want to get to centered.

My Notepad++ Code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    
    Ent1    db 0dh,0ah, "   Enter First Number  : "
            db 0dh,0ah, "   Enter Second Number : "
            db 0dh,0ah, "   Equvalent           : $"
    
.code
main proc
    
    mov ax,@data                    ;initialize ds
    mov ds,ax
    
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx, Ent1
    int 21h
    
    mov ah,4Ch                      ;end here
    int 21h
    
main endp
end main
```

logic code I want to do:

[image]

Example Output that need to show:

[image]

Comment: You'll have to calculate how many spaces to print yourself, based on screen width.  Either assume it's 80, or query it somehow.  Then using the known length of the string you're going to print on that line, figure out what column it should start at.

Comment: my bad i'am new in centering in column the string so i don;t know what codes do i use...

Comment: @DevilBlacklist Did my answer below not address the issue from your question? I see that you've moved on to a new question (that I have answered too) without responding to this one.

Answer (score 1):

In order to center a string on the screen you need to position the cursor where the string's first character is to be printed. Use next calculation to find out:

```
CursorColumn = (ScreenWidth - StringLength) / 2
```

The [BIOS.GetCurrentVideoMode function 0Fh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0108.htm) returns in the `AH` register the number of columns that the current screen has.

To establish the StringLength, don't forget to include the length of the expected input. Results will look nicer especially if the input is somewhat longer.

Next code will reproduce what's on the screen in your screenshot:

```
Msg1 db "Input First Number: $"
Msg2 db "Input SecondNumber: $"
Msg3 db "The sum is: $"
    
...

mov  ah, 0Fh  ; BIOS.GetCurrentVideoMode
int  10h      ; -> AL (video mode), AH (columns), BH (display page)

mov  dl, ah   ; ScreenWidth
sub  dl, 21   ; minus StringLength (length of the message + 1 for the inputted digit)
shr  dl, 1    ; divide by 2
mov  dh, 11   ; Row
mov  ah, 02h  ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
int  10h

push dx       ; (1)
mov  dx, offset Msg1
mov  ah, 09h  ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h
pop  dx       ; (1)
```

For the 2nd message you would just need to increment the cursor row. That's why I preserved the value in `DX` on the stack.

```
inc  dh       ; Row + 1 (same column)
mov  ah, 02h  ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
int  10h

push dx       ; (2)
mov  dx, offset Msg2
mov  ah, 09h  ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h
pop  dx       ; (2)
```

And for the 3rd message you would need to increment twice

```
add  dh, 2    ; Row + 2 (same column)
mov  ah, 02h  ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
int  10h

mov  dx, offset Msg2
mov  ah, 09h  ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h
```

---

A similar approach holds to center the strings vertically.

```
CursorRow = (ScreenHeight - NumberOfStrings) / 2
          = (25 - 4) / 2
          = 10
```

This is 1 less than the code that you have showed us because I have included the blank row! Without that blank row you would get (25 - 3) / 2 = 11